# Find a document using expression tree and nested BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Querying documents via fluent interface, using nested BsonDocument properties fails with following message:

```
"Method 'Boolean Contains(MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' declared on type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray' cannot be called with instance of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue"
```

this is code block, used:

```cs
Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> entityEqualityExpression = entity => (entity.Body[tags].AsBsonArray).Contains("testTag");
mongoDb.GetCollection<Entity>("Entities").Find(predicate);
```

But works fine, when casing is performed manually (not via AsBsonArray property):

```cs
Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> entityEqualityExpression = entity => ((BsonArray)entity.Body[tags]).Contains("testTag");
mongoDb.GetCollection<Entity>("Entities").Find(predicate);
```

How is it possible, if AsBsonArray property is simply performing same casting:

```cs
get => (BsonArray) this;
```

Comment: This error is not related to type casting, it's about not supplying check predicate, where's it's expecting Boolean it's getting a `BsonValue`. Version which is correct as per you does or produce result as expected

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I'm not sure what do you mean by 'not supplying check predicate' - both expressions are pointing to execution of Enumerable.Contains(..) extension method, which returns Boolean.